# Need to displaying number of videos displaying in Curosol using selenium

Tags: selenium

Need to displaying number of videos displaying in Curosol using selenium.

Tried with xpath :

```
homePageNumberOfPlaylist_XPATH = //div[@class='jcarousel']/descendant::ul/descendant::li

driver.findElement(By.xpath("homePageNumberOfPlaylist_XPATH")).getSize();
```

[image]

but getting error as

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Remove the apostrophes from `"homePageNumberOfPlaylist_XPATH"`

Comment: In addition use the id of the div instead. No need to use the descendant.  //div[@id='jcarouselHome']/ul/li

Comment: Hi Grasshopper if i used ID or CLASS 'no such element' error displaying.

Comment: @karthik Maybe you need to wait for the element to be visible before accessing